# Why does my program stop crashing if I call malloc instead of GetMem?

Tags: delphi, memory-management, delphi-2009, malloc

I am calling a C DLL from a Delphi 2009 application and I keep getting errors when memory allocated by GetMem or AllocMem is passed to the DLL. The only way around I could avoid these errors was by using malloc from msvcrt.dll. What is malloc doing that the built-in memory routines aren't, and how can I get the built-in ones to work? I really don't like bypassing the built-in memory manager.

Comment: What sort of errors are you getting?  There shouldn't be any problems unless the C dll tries to free or realloc the memory you passed to it, which it really shouldn't be doing.

Comment: Agreed, but unfortunately "shouldn't be" and "isn't" are different things, and far too frequently so.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The dll has an option to take control of the memory and I was using it. I will rewrite my function to keep control of the memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the DLL ever attempts to free that memory or otherwise manipulate the memory allocation (e.g. expand/contract it), that would explain it.  Mixing memory allocation systems is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to Calling Convention, stdcall or cdecl
.